# Is there a way for R to run a script and on error return non-0 to the shell?

Tags: r

Given a file `script.R` containing 3 lines :

```
print('hello')
stop('user error')
print('world')
```

we can run it :

```
$ R -f script.R
> print('hello')
[1] "hello"
> stop('user error')
Error: user error
> print('world')
[1] "world"
```

but that continues after the error. I want it to halt the script on error. This does that :

```
$ R -e "source('script.R')"
> source('script.R')
[1] "hello"
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : user error
Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval
```

Good. It halted running the script on the error. But the return value to the shell is 0 (success) :

```
$ echo $?
0
```

Is there anyway to run the script, halt on error, and return non-zero to the shell?  I searched and I couldn't find an answer.

I could grep the output file for the text "Error" but that has some risk that needs managing; e.g. greping the wrong output file somehow and two or more runs writing to the same file. Those issues can be managed but returning non-zero to the shell would be simpler and more robust. Adding a line to the end of the script is also a workaround since I'd need to add that line to all the scripts.

Comment: On my machine the execution of `R -f script.R` is halted after `stop('user error')`. And `echo $?` returns `1`. (Ubuntu 15.04, R version 3.2.2 Patched).

Comment: @Pascal  Odd. I am also Ubuntu 15.04,  R 3.2.2

Comment: Yes, odd. I just saved your example in a `script.R` file located in my home directory, and ran `R -f script.R`. Could you try maybe `R --vanilla -f script.R`?

Comment: @Pascal Bingo!  Now returns 1.  Looking in my .Rprofile ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Pascal in comments, it turned out that in my .Rprofile I had :

```
options(error=quote(dump.frames()))
```

When I run with `--vanilla` as well to prevent my .Rprofile from being loaded :

```
$ R --vanilla -f script.R
> print('hello')
[1] "hello"
> stop('user error')
Error: user error
Execution halted
$ echo $?
1
```

Which is exactly what I wanted and solves the problem. Thanks @Pascal!